# KendoUI Grid: Add fields to Datasource dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, grid, datasource

I have a Kendo DataSource that I'm binding to a grid.  I'm adding a field dyanmically.  This all works fine until I put a template on the column that I add dynamically.

Model Building:

```
            model = kendo.data.Model.define({
                id: "Id",
                fields: {

                }
            });


            model.fields["CreationDate"] = { type: "date" };
```

I then assign the model to the model property of the datasource.  My grid is created like:

```
$("#Grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: UserDS,
            columns: [
                { "field": "CreationDate",  template: '#= kendo.toString(CreationDate, "g") #' }                
            ]            
        });
```

When I try to add a new record to this grid I get an error saying CreationDate is not define.  If I remove the template part of the field definition it works.  Also if I change the model to add the field as part of the model definition it works even with the template.  I would expect the same end result from both approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var model ={
                id: "Id",
                fields: {}
            };
model.fields["CreationDate"] = { type: "date" };
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sbb5Z/1599/

Comment: Excellent, that works. Thanks.  Any idea why? I've compared the generated model property by property and they look identical using a static and dynamic approach.